# initial values for parallel coordinates using d3js

Tags: d3.js, parallel-coordinates

I am using parallel coordinates example of this link
https://bl.ocks.org/jasondavies/1341281

I want to set initial range values for particular axis...Can anyone please let me know..

Comment: in the doc of d3.brush` you can find how to set the range with a function call

Comment: Hey Thanks for the help... in the brush documentation I got hint to do it..   d3.select(this).call(y[d].brush = d3.svg.brush().y(y[d]).extent([1.3, 1.8]).on("brush", brush));   added extent(min,max) but additionally I need to call brush event to apply that extent

Answer (score 0):

d3.select(this).call(y[d].brush = d3.svg.brush().y(y[d]).extent([1.3, 1.8]).on("brush", brush));

just changed this line by adding extent([min.max]) this will draw brush but will not trigger event to update foreground-background. So need to call brush() manually in the end.